# In shell, print only the specific line/word from command's output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This is the output snippet of cloc command

```
C/C++ Header
 same                            0              0          42812          19019
 modified                       33              0            128            434
 added                           3             63            367            207
 removed                         0            105            265            479
Perl
 same                            0              0              0              0
 modified                        0              0              0              0
 added                           2              0              0              0
 removed                         0              0              0              0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:
  same                            0              0          54150          81007
  modified                       82              0            252           2137
  added                           7            184            802           1281
  removed                         0            234            734           1499
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using Shell command, how to print only 82, 2137 (in row modified) and 7, 1281(in row added) ? I need to print only these 4 numbers under "SUM:" and ignore the rest.

Comment: are the multiple block of similar layout in the output, i.e. multiple `SUM:` sections that you want to process? Good luck.

Comment: No, just one SUM section, which will be at the end always, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the number of added/modified files/lines between two versions of a project, you can do it correctly and robustly with `cloc`'s XML output:

```
 cloc --xml --out=report.xml --diff  bash-4.2.tar.gz bash-4.3.tar.gz 

 xmlstarlet < report.xml sel -t \
    -m /diff_results/modified/total -v @sum_files -o ' ' -v @code -nl \
    -m /diff_results/added/total    -v @sum_files -o ' ' -v @code -nl
```

`xmlstarlet` can output the numbers in any format you want. This specific example uses this format (modified files/lines followed by added files/lines):

```
15 11157
203 6058
```

The benefit of processing computer readable output rather than human readable output is that it won't break if `cloc` slightly changes its output formatting in the future.

Comment: Bravo! Definitely the most robust and futureproof approach here.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '/SUM/{start=1; next} start && NF==5 && $1=="modified"{a=$2; b=$NF} 
     start && NF==5 && $1=="added"{c=$2; d=$NF} END {print a, b, c, d}' file
82 2137 7 1281
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version using `grep` and `awk` (where in.txt is the file with context):

```
$ grep -A10 SUM in.txt | egrep "added|modified" | awk '{print $2" "$5}'
82 2137
7 1281
```

The first grep will match everything after `SUM`, second grep only rows containing `added` and `modified` (after SUM), awk will print columns 2 & 5.

Instead of awk, you can also use: `tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3,6`

or as suggested by [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952042/in-shell-print-only-the-specific-line-word-from-commands-output/31952540#comment51815055_31952540):

```
$ grep -A10 SUM in.txt | awk '/added|modified/ {print $2" "$5}'
```

---

Here is example using `ex` (without using pipes):

```
$ ex -s +'1,/SUM/d|v/modified\|added/d|norm dWW2dW' +%p -cq! file_or_/dev/stdin
  82           2137
  7            1281
```

Replace `-cq!` with `-cwq` to edit in-place.

Comment: Why would you use both tools separately? Startup overhead for grep is going to outweigh any performance advantage over doing the scanning in awk.

Comment: For readability and simplicity. Using grep you've full control what is returned, then awk has a simple task of printing two single columns (it can be always replaced by `cut`). This syntax is useful, when you don't know awk so much.

Comment: `awk '/added|modified/ {print $2" "$5}'`, and the second grep is replaced. The very-slightly-trickier part is setting a flag in awk after you've seen `SUM`, but, well, that's only *very* slightly trickier, and already shown in anubhava's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe your output into something like this:

```
yourcommand |  awk '/modified/||/added/{print $2","$5}' |tail -n 2
82,2137
7,1281
```

Comment: Doesn't filter for only contents under the first match for `SUM`.

Comment: The OP pointed out that the Sum section is always at the end. A bit hard coded, but simple.

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you **really** want to do this in shell rather than using awk:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -f # disable globbing to allow string-splitting abuse below

found_header=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [ "$line" = "SUM:" ] && found_header=1
  [ "$found_header" = 1  ] || continue

  set -- $line # Ugly practice; only use with set -f above

  case $1 in
    modified|added) printf '%s\n' "$2,$5" ;;
  esac
done
```